# Optional struct argument in Objective-C++

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

I have to hack on an Objective-C++ project and I am trying to figure out how optionals work there. What's the analogous of `std::optional` there?

Simple example:

```
- (void)foo:(CGSize)first
     second:(nullable CGSize*)second;
```

I can now pass `nil` if I want to omit `second`.

However, I cannot figure out how to construct a pointer to CGSize to pass it to `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you're using Objective-C++ throughout (the implementation and the consumer of the API are both Objective-C++, not Objective-C) you *can just use `std::optional`:*

```
- (void)foo:(CGSize)first
     second:(std::optional<CGSize>)second;
```

2. If your method needs to be callable from Objective-C, you can use a pointer, as you indeed have in your code snippet. However, for non-object types (non-`@interface`, non-`id`, non-`@protocol`) you use `NULL` instead of `nil` in Objective-C, much as you do in C. (You can interchangeably use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` in Objective-C++, with the former providing all the advantages it also gives in pure C++.)